# Custom headers are not sent with my AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I am trying to make an AJAX request from my client to my NodeJS/ExpressJS backend.

However, when the request is fired, my backend receive it well but doesn't recognize the custom headers . e.g.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/foo",
        headers: {"authorization": "Bearer 12345"},
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        encode: true,
      })
```

in Node , when I do `req.headers['authorization']` I get `undefined`.

I don't understand what I did wrong.

Any advice ?

Comment: What do you see in your browser's dev tools _Network_ panel? Are the correct headers sent with the request? What triggers the AJAX request? If it's a button click, is that button within a `<form>`? If so, perhaps your form is submitting normally without custom headers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether the request you're making is **cross-url** or not, but if it is try the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "yoururl",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    xhrFields: {
         withCredentials: true // edited
    },
    //...
});
```

I ran into the same error a few times before and it was due to me not adding this important attribute to the request - **when** authentication is required.